# R osmdata package: opq() function downloads even out of the box

Tags: r, ggplot2, openstreetmap

I have this code and I'm using RStudio

```
library(tidyverse)
library(osmdata)

q <- opq(bbox = c(2.34560,48.86015,2.35152,48.86145)) # around Rue Berger (Paris, France)


all_Data <- osmdata_sf(q)

ggplot() +
  geom_sf(
    data = all_Data$osm_lines,
    inherit.aes = FALSE,
    color = "black",
    size = .4,
    alpha = .8 )
```

when I plot this I have this

[image: 1]

but it should be around this photo

[image: 2]

As you can see longitude and latitude (min and max) are out the indicated box.

I don't understand why the opq() function doesn't download only the date of the indicated box.

Where am I wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It will download any objects that pass through the selected box, so these are just longer lines (roads, rivers, railways, boundaries, etc) that happen to pass through the box.

Comment: @AndrewGustar I'm not so sure about this answer. Some lines are completely outside the box and not connected to other lines inside the box.